# Slim framework 4; return Formr-form

Tags: php, slim, slim-4

In Slim framework 4; How can I return a Formr-form in my controller as a response to a get-request?

```php
$app->group('/timer', function (Group $group) {
    $group->get('/', function (Request $request, Response $response) {

        $form = new Formr\Formr();

        // $form->create_form('Name')
        // die();
        $response->getBody()->write($form->create_form('Name'));
        return $response;
    });
});
```

The code outputs nothing. However, if I uncomment the two lines, it outputs (as expected):

```
<form action="/index.php" id="myFormr" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<input type="hidden" name="FormrID" value="myFormr"><label for="name">Name</label> 
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" />


<button type="submit" name="button" id="button">Submit</button>


</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Formr documentations](https://formr.github.io/#quick-start):

> Formr will automatically echo form elements and messages to the
> screen, and this is usually fine. However, in some instances - such as
> when using a templating framework - this is not an option. In these
> cases simply pass the word hush and then manually echo your elements
> and messages.
>
> `$form = new Formr\Formr('bootstrap', 'hush');`

The default value for the first parameter of `Formr\Formr` constructor is an empty string, so in your case you should create new Formr instance with an empty string `''` as the first parameter ann `'hush'` as the second parameter:

```php
$app->group('/timer', function (Group $group) {
    $group->get('/', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
        
        // required change
        $form = new Formr\Formr('', 'hush');
             
        $response->getBody()->write($form->create_form('Name'));
        return $response;
    });
});
```